# Angular: What happened to the core.module style?

Tags: angular

**Tl;dr**: It seems the `core.module` style is no longer part of the official [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide), but it must have been removed only recently. What is the new best practice for importing singleton services and why was the style removed?

---

I just read [this](https://robferguson.org/blog/2018/11/05/getting-started-with-angular-material/) guide on getting started with Angular Material and it states

```
    Then (as per the Angular Style Guide) I created a Core module
```

I checked the [Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide), but can't seem to find the guideline referenced here. During my search I stumbled over the following sources:

- [A blogpost](https://medium.com/@benmohamehdi/angular-best-practices-coremodule-vs-sharedmodule-25f6721aa2ef) from **Nov. '18** explaining the difference between core.module and shared.module.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695931/angular2-coremodule-vs-sharedmodule) from **Oct. '17** with a very detailed explanation of the core.module.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477221/angular-6-coremodule-and-sharedmodule) from **Jul. '18**, which went unnoticed.

The last Question refers to the `core.module` style with this link:

```
    https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module
```

It seems the `#core-feature-module` anchor has been removed and is no longer part of the official Angular style guide. Only the [shared feature module guideline](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module) remains.

Why was the `core.module` guideline removed? What is the new best practice for importing singletons such as services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply said it [never been required](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#say-goodbye-to-angularjs):

> You may also completely remove the following files. They are AngularJS module configuration files and not needed in Angular:
>
> - app/app.module.ajs.ts
> - app/app.config.ts
> - **app/core/core.module.ts**
> - app/core/phone/phone.module.ts
> - app/phone-detail/phone-detail.module.ts
> - app/phone-list/phone-list.module.ts

As for the [reason why it got removed](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29848#issuecomment-483321775):

> @jenniferfell @brandonroberts fyi. @jenniferfell we removed `CoreModule` as a recommended technique because now the preferred way of providing services is using `providedIn`, however @bisonfoutu has a great point. I think the focus of this issue might be best suited for a style guide point on Feature Modules or `SharedModule` section, but I'd love to hear what the team and community have to say.
>
> IMO, where it could go were we to come to the conclusion that we should advise this technique: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module
>
> Thanks for filing this issue, @bisonfoutu!!
>
> Thoughts are welcome! ✨

Comment: I understand the file is listed as an unneeded configuration file in the [Upgrading from AngularJS](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#say-goodbye-to-angularjs) guide and frankly I don't understand why. However, there are countless sources from the past years referring to the `core.module` style in the context of Angular ^2, and it seems until recently it was still part of the official style guide. My question remains.

Comment: @codepearlex reasonable enough. I added a citation from the git response about it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! The `providedIn` option of the `@Injectable()` decorator renders the `core.module` style useless, because it was intended for singleton imports only. However, the blog post in which I originally read about the `core.module` recommended importing Angular Material there. It seems this is was bad advice, even back when the `core.module` was still considered best practice, because Angular Material is not a service, but a collection of components.

Comment: BTW: The new best practice is described in the [Providing a service](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#providing-a-service) style in the current [Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide). Thanks for shedding some light on this.